# Difference between Proc univarite and Proc severity for fitting continuous (positive support) distribution

Tags: sas, model-fitting, goodness-of-fit

My goal is to fit a data to any distribution which has positive support. (weibull(2p), gamma(2p), pareto(2p), lognormal (2p),exponential(1P)). First attempt,i used proc univariate.This is my code

```
proc univariate data=fit plot outtable=table;
   var week1;
   histogram / exp gamma lognormal weibull pareto;
   inset n mean(5.3) std='Standar Deviasi'(5.3) 
          / pos = ne  header = 'Summary Statistics';
   axis1 label=(a=90 r=0);
   run;
```

The first thing i noticed, there's no kolmogorov statistic shown for weibull distribution.Then i used proc severity instead.

```
proc severity data=fit print=all plots(histogram kernel)=all;
loss week1; 
dist exp pareto gamma logn weibull;
run;
```

Now, i got the KS statistic for weibull distribution.
Then i compared KS statistic produced by proc severity and proc univariate. They're different. Why? Which one should i use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have access to SAS/ETS so cannot confirm this with `proc severity`, but I imagine that the difference you are seeing come down to the way the distribution parameters are fitted.

With your `proc univriate` code you are not requesting estimation for several of the parameters (some are in some cases set to 1 or 0 by default, see [sigma](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/66703/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_univariate_syntax09.htm#procstat.univariate.hist_sigma) and [theta](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/66703/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_univariate_syntax09.htm#procstat.univariate.hist_theta) in the user guide). For example:

```
data have;
    do i = 1 to 1000;
        x = rand("weibull", 5, 5);
        output;
    end;
run;
ods graphics on;
proc univariate data = have;
    var x;
    /* Request maximum liklihood estimate of scale and threshold parameters */
    histogram / weibull(theta = EST sigma = EST);
    /* Request maximum liklihood estimate of scale parameter and 0 as threshold */
    histogram / weibull;
run;
```

You will note that when an estimate of theta is requested SAS also produces the KS statistic, this is due to the way that SAS estimates the fit statistic requiring know distribution parameters (full explanation [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/66703/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_univariate_details51.htm#procstat.univariate.tuniedf)).

My guess is that you are seeing different fit statistics between the two procedures because either they are returning slightly different fits, or they use different calculations for the estimation of fit statistics. If you are interested you can investigate how they perform their parameter estimation in the user guide ([`proc severity`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63348/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_severity_sect015.htm) and [`proc univariate`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/66703/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_univariate_details21.htm)). If you wanted to investigate further you could force the distribution parameters to match in both procedures and then compare the fit statistics to see how far they differ.

I would recommend that if possible you use only one of the procedure, and that you select the one that best fits your needs in terms of output.

Comment: I've just realized that proc severity only fit weibull distribution with two parameter. That's what i need. But is it possible to use proc univariate to fit weibull (2P) distribution? it's look like specifying theta doesn't give what i really want.Thx a lot!

Comment: Looking [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63348/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_severity_sect015.htm) and [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/66703/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_univariate_details37.htm#procstat.univariate.fitted_weibull) it seems that the additional parameters are due to `proc univariate` fitting the PDF to the histogram rather than the underlying data. The PDFs are equivalent when `v=1, h=1, θ=0` in `proc univariate`, where `c = τ` and `σ = θ` (to convert `proc univariate` parameters to `proc severity` names).